# Active Admin Form with Hstore Column - Unpermitted Param Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, hstore

I am using ActiveAdmin(1.0.0.pre1) with Rails 4.2.0.

I have a model namely `Provider`. It has a `hstore` column `current_address`.

For this hstore column I have a key called full_address, for which I want a edit. 
I followed this link https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2032 to achieve this. The form loads correctly.

**However I am getting a error `Unpermitted parameters: current_address`.** As you can see I have already added `current_address` in my `permit_params` list.

Can anyone suggest me what is going wrong here and how can I fix it. Thanks :)

```
ActiveAdmin.register Provider do
  permit_params :dob, :current_address
  menu parent: 'User'
  config.sort_order = 'id_asc'
  actions :all, except: [:new]
  filter :mobile_number
  filter :id

  index do
    selectable_column
    column :id
    column :mobile_number
    column :name
    column :gender
    column :dob
    column :current_address
    actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Provider Details' do
      f.input :dob, as: :datepicker
      f.fields_for :current_address do |current_address|
        current_address.input :full_address,
                              input_html: {value: f.object.current_address.
                                                  try(:[], 'full_address')}
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

When you permit `:current_address` in your strong parameters, it only permits scalar value.
https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#permitted-scalar-values

So you need to specify permitted keys for hash. In your case just write:

```
permit_params :dob, { current_address: [:full_address, :any_other_custom_key] }
```